# Delete lead trigger not work after import

Tags: apex, trigger, data-loader, import

I'm trying to delete a lead according to condition I have, I wrote my code and it works on manual add new lead. But I tried it using Data Loader tool the trigger not fired and record created.

```
trigger deleteUnwantedLead on Lead (after insert) {
    delete [select id from lead where id in :Trigger.new and Email like '%spam%' ];

}
```

Comment: are you sure that mapping is correct and email field is filled?

Comment: @kurunve yes and email inserted as it from excel sheet too.